# How to get the main NSMenu in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsmenu

I would like to get the `main NSMenu` in Swift for execution the following code `NSMenu(title: "ApplicationName").autoenablesItems = false`. I don't know what to insert as `title`, because it seems that it can't get a reference to it and disable `autoenablesItems`, because I can't set a `MenuItem`'s `enabled`-Property.

Comment: You can get a reference to the main menu of the application with `NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainMenu`, but – as mentioned in the other question – `validateMenuItem` is the usual way to enable and disable menu items programmatically and dynamically.

Comment: Still not working, function is called and is able to change title, but the Item is still not disabled. I tried now `return false` and in addition to that I also tried `menuItem.enabled = false` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick comment, hoping it helps someone else with the same question. The answer to this question is to add the main menu or menu items automatically created in the storyboard to appDelegate and create related code.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var saveMenuItem: NSMenuItem! // Can be added by dragging from the storyboard

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
        
    }
}
```